# How to upload a pandas dataframe as a csv stream without saving on disk?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I want to upload a pandas dataframe to a server as csv file without saving it on the disk. Is there a way to create a more or less "fake csv" file which pretends to be a real file?

Here is some example code:

First I get my data from a sql query and store it as a dataframe.
In the `upload_ga_data` function I want to have something with this logic:

```
 media = MediaFileUpload('df',
                      mimetype='application/octet-stream',
                      resumable=False)
```

Full example:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
import pymysql
import pandas as pd
con = x

ga_query = """
    SELECT XXXXX
    """

df = pd.read_sql_query(ga_query,con)

df.to_csv('ga_export.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index = False)

def upload_ga_data():
    try:
        media = MediaFileUpload('ga_export.csv',
                          mimetype='application/octet-stream',
                          resumable=False)
        daily_upload = service.management().uploads().uploadData(
                accountId=accountId,
                webPropertyId=webPropertyId,
                customDataSourceId=customDataSourceId,
                media_body=media).execute()
        print ("Upload was successfull")
    except TypeError as error:
      # Handle errors in constructing a query.
      print ('There was an error in constructing your query : %s' % error)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The required behavior is possible using [stream](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html):

> to create a more or less "fake csv" file which pretends to be a real file

Python makes *File Descriptor* (with `open`) and *Stream* (with `io.StringIO`) behave similarly. Then anywhere you can use a file descriptor can also use a String Stream.

> The easiest way to create a text stream is with open(), optionally
>   specifying an encoding:
>
> ```
> f = open("myfile.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
> ```
>
> In-memory text streams are also available as StringIO objects:
>
> ```
> f = io.StringIO("some initial text data")
> ```
>
> The text stream API is described in detail in the documentation of
>   TextIOBase.

In Pandas you can do it with any [function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) having `path_or_buf` argument in its [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature), such as `to_csv`:

> `DataFrame.to_csv(`**`path_or_buf`**`=None, sep=', ', na_rep='', float_format=None, columns=None, header=True, index=True, index_label=None, mode='w', encoding=None, compression=None, quoting=None, quotechar='"', line_terminator='\n', chunksize=None, tupleize_cols=None, date_format=None, doublequote=True, escapechar=None, decimal='.')`

Following code exports a dummy DataFrame in CSV format into a String Stream (not physical file, in-memory octet-stream):

```
import io
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(10)))

stream = io.StringIO()
df.to_csv(stream, sep=";")
```

When you want to get access to the stream content, just issue:

```
>>> stream.getvalue()
';0\n0;0\n1;1\n2;2\n3;3\n4;4\n5;5\n6;6\n7;7\n8;8\n9;9\n'
```

It returns the content without having the need to use a real file.

Comment: Excellent, simple explanation and solid demonstration - thank you!

Comment: I tried to upload with as 
`http.MediaIoBaseUpload(stream.getvalue(), mimetype=mimetype, resumable=True)` but it throws a `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` error instead. Am I missing something or does the stream doesn't really work for the upload?

Comment: @AlphaCR just pass the stream. Does not return the value which is interpreted as a file path.

Comment: passing just the stream would only result in `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.StringIO`. Perhaps its due to something else?

Comment: Well without a [mcve] it is hard to tell. But your error says that this object does not accept StringIO and expect bytes. Maybe you will get success with a `io.BytesIO` object.

Comment: @AlphaCR If you or anyone else coming here in future gets that error message, check if you are accidentally calling MediaFileUpload instead of MediaIOBaseUpload

Answer (score 1):

Though the other answer is an excellent start, there may be some who are confused on how to complete op's whole task.  Here is a way to go from writing a dataframe to a stream to preparing that stream for upload using Google apiclient.http module.  A key difference from op's attempt is that I pass the stream itself to a MediaIOBaseUpload instead of a MediaFileUpload.  The file is assumed to be utf-8 like OP's file.  This runs fine for me until the media is being uploaded, then I have an error " self._fp.write(s.encode('ascii', 'surrogateescape'))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 2313: ordinal not in range(128)"

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

from apiclient.http import MediaIOBaseUpload  # Changed this from MediaFileUpload

df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(10)))

stream = io.StringIO()
# writing df to the stream instead of a file:
df.to_csv(stream, sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index = False)
try:
    media = MediaIOBaseUpload(stream,
                          mimetype='application/octet-stream',
                          resumable=False)

#### Your upload logic here using media just created ####

except HttpError as error:

    #### Handle your errors in uploading here ####
```

Because I have a unicode character, I developed the alternative code which accomplishes the same thing but can handle the unicode characters.

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

from apiclient.http import MediaIOBaseUpload  # Changed this from MediaFileUpload

df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(10)))

records = df.to_csv(line_terminator='\r\n', index=False).encode('utf-8')
bytes = io.BytesIO(records)

try:
    media = MediaIOBaseUpload(bytes,
                          mimetype='application/octet-stream',
                          resumable=False)

#### Your upload logic here using media just created ####

except HttpError as error:

    #### Handle your errors in uploading here ####
```

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseUpload
```

versus @Katherine's:

```
from apiclient.http import MediaIOBaseUpload
```

But other than that, @Katherine's alternative solution worked perfectly for me as I was developing a solution to write a dataframe to a csv file in Google Drive running from a Google Cloud Function.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32485304)